# How to find how long the mail was opened using mailgun

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mailgun

I am using mailgun Api for sending mail and tracking open,click, hardbounce. my question is there any way to find how long time the mail was opened by user.

Comment: No, you can't know that. You can't even know if someone open and close mail letter if no interact (i.e. no links are clicked). You can't know if user delete email from inbox wether read or not. Anything you can measure is something that happens on your own server when and if user click link in received email.

Comment: I am able to track open and click, but i want how much duration the user has read the mail i.e. how long mail was opened.

Comment: You can't know that.